Grinding an inside radius on deckel SO
I'm trying to find out if it is possible to grind an accurate inside radius on a deckel SO. Does anyone know if this is possible? I tried googling it but wasn't able to find anything useful and then ChatGPT said something about an "Internal grinding spindle" but I can't find any information on this.

How accurate? Have you considered that you can use an inaccurate tool to remove material efficiently and follow it up with a more accurate tool that is slower and more expensive per unit of material removed?
